# apt-cacher ng "an error occured while reading this file, some contents may have been ignored."

Tags: apt

I've been getting the following message every day from the `apt-cacher-ng` cron job:

```
/etc/cron.daily/apt-cacher-ng:
Error(s) occured while updating volatile index files for apt-cacher-ng.
Please visit http://proxy.localnet:3142/report.html to rerun the
expiration manually or check the error message(s) in the current log file(s).
```

When I run it, I always get errors on the exact same files. It is always the *.xz files.

```
An error occured while reading this file, some contents may have been ignored. Tag
Parsing metadata in debrep/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages.xz
An error occured while reading this file, some contents may have been ignored. Tag
Parsing metadata in debrep/dists/jessie/main/binary-i386/Packages.xz
An error occured while reading this file, some contents may have been ignored. Tag
Parsing metadata in debrep/dists/jessie/main/source/Sources.xz
```

I delete them and the apt-cacher-ng web interface is happy, but as soon as I do an apt-get update on one of the clients. These files are back with exactly the same error.

I've been searching around for a solution to the, but can't seem to find anyone with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd exactly the same problem and found this [official Debian bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=731804). Installing a newer version of *apt-cacher-ng* package solved the issue for me. If you're still using wheezy (like I do), try to download and install the [backport](https://packages.debian.org/de/wheezy-backports/apt-cacher-ng) manually.

Cheers,
Michael

Comment: Thanks. That is a bit of an obscure one. It now makes sense as it started when I got my GTX 960 and had to use the NVidia driver in backports. I did not think that it was related, as the report only comes the next day from apt-cacher-ng cron jobs.